# Set automatic buffer name to folder/filename or clojure namespace

Tags: emacs, clojure, buffer

I'm new to emacs and wanting my buffers to be automatically named folder/filename or clojure.namespace.filename. I've found [Uniquify](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Uniquify.html) which will rename conflicting buffers but I can't see how to use it as the default. Is there a way to do this or alternatively, a more idiomatic way of identifying buffers in emacs?

Comment: The buffer is usually the name of the file.  Instead of changing the buffer name, how about a setting that puts the path + filename in the mode-line or up above in the title of the frame?  Have you looked at `M-x buffer-menu`?  There are a bunch of Emacs packages that use a similar buffer listing.  Have you looked at the buffer-menu that drops down from the menu-bar?  There is a similar buffer context pop-up menu that is available for the mouse.

Comment: You can make uniquify the default way to produce buffer names. `M-x customize-group <return> uniquify <return>`

Comment: Or do you mean you want uniquify produced names even when you have no name conflicts? If so there is a `rename-buffer` elisp command, and you could use it to construct a new buffer name based on the file visited and the buffer contents in a custom elisp function.

Comment: I'm trying to have a way of identifying the path of the file in an idiomatic way to emacs. In the project I'm working on there are the same or similar filename in different paths so customising the mode-line could be good. I think I'll start with customising the mode-line and maybe look at rename-buffer if that doesn't work. If you make your comment an answer I'll pick it @noisesmith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use uniquify `M-x customize-group <return> uniquify <return>`, which allows including enough of the relative path in the buffer name to differentiate buffers.

If you want to use the clojure namespace of the file as the buffer name there is the `rename-buffer` function, which could be passed a name generated with the help of clojure-mode which can tell you what namespace that file defines via [clojure-expected-ns](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/blob/master/clojure-mode.el#L1154) or [clojure-find-ns](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/blob/master/clojure-mode.el#L1189).

There is also the option of setting a [header](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HeaderLine) or [mode-line](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ModeLineConfiguration) entry besides the buffer name.

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/smart-mode-line for this, it doesn't show the buffer name and instead shows the path.